# iOS app DidBecomeActive shows the last screen before DidEnterBackground for a second

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, appdelegate

I need to show a passcode screen on `applicationDidBecomeActive` (users press home button, touch the app again on home screen). However, every time the app launches again from home screen it shows the last screen before the users press the home button for a splash second then my app delegate presents the Passcode view.

I have try adding a white view on top in `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` but no helps. I also try registering a nofitication on the ViewController of the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` noti to add a white subview on top but it still shows the last screen on resume.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appHasGoneInBackground)
                                              name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];

- (void)appHasGoneInBackground {
    HNAppDelegate *appDelegate = (HNAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.currentVC = self;
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgLight1"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

That did not work either. How do I not show the last screen on `applicationDidBecomeActive`. The E-trade app does that by showing a splash screen E-trade image. Thanks

Comment: There's a WWDC video about the subject. Watch it.

Comment: Do you know the title of the video? Thanks